# Playback Complete In Windows Media Player

Tags: python, subprocess, windows-media-player

I launched a `subprocess` to using its `call` method to play a video on Window Media Player.

eg. 
    `subprocess.call('"C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Media Player/wmplayer.exe"  "C:/Users/Public/Videos/Sample Videos/Wildlife.wmv"')`

Now, how can I check if the playback is completed in the player for that particular video.

Is there is any direct Api available for the Windows Media Player 
Or 
there is a way to listen to the subprocess command launched using `Popen`

eg.

```
p = subprocess.Popen('"C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Media Player/wmplayer.exe"  "C:/Users/Public/Videos/Sample Videos/Wildlife.wmv"')
# while the placback is happening
    p.wait()
# otherwise
    p.kill()
```

Comment: Can we assume that the user is not going to fiddle with the controls and that the file will playback uninterrupted?

Comment: sorry for late reply, yes user won't be using the playback options at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct WMP Api:

`subprocess.call('"C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Media Player/wmplayer.exe" /play /close "C:/Users/Public/Videos/Sample Videos/Wildlife.wmv"')`

adding **/play /close** will do the needful.

http://support.microsoft.com/KB/241422 for more options.

Hope it will help someone in future.

Comment: The linked article is for mplayer2, not wmplayer. /play /close are not valid options for wmplayer. See see this link for valid options for wmplayer.exe: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562624(v=vs.85).aspx